# Get column alias of column in query?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the MySQL .NET Connector, and I'm wondering how I can get the real and alias names of columns in a query resultset.

Consider the following example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM Projects
```

In this scenario, I would like to (from the DataSet) retrieve both the value "COUNT(*)" and the value "Amount" as strings.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get it like that, make it as two columns in the query itself:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM Projects
```

Comment: That won't work in my scenario. I am looping through all columns, and for each column it is important that I get both the alias and the original name.

Comment: What do you mean by "original name" actually? "Count(*)" or some other else.